# Google Cloud Firewall/VPN/Network settings backup/export/import

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wonder if there is a way to backup or export the Firewall rules, VPN settings 
and network settings in google cloud to be imported back in a later date/new account/after failed change/etc.

I can export firewall rules to a text using `gcloud compute firewall-rules list` and then add `gcloud compute firewall-rules create` to each rule somehow but I'm trying to find some easier solution.

Also it looks like there is no way of creating firewall rules after exporting them to yaml format using this command: `gcloud compute firewall-rules list --format=yaml`

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there isn't any direct command or GUI option available in the GCP platform. However, there is an on going similar "Feature Request" in Google Cloud platform.

You can check [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/70711597) link on this matter, as any new updates will be posted there. You can also make any suggestions/corrections by commenting that link as well.